# Verify that preceding text input matches text input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am writing javascript code to verify that the preceding text input matches the current text input. Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Tests</h2>

<form>
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ><br>
    <label for="password2">Confirm Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" class='verify'><br>

    <button type='submit'>Submit></button>
  </form>
 
<div id="errormsgs">
  </div>

<script src="validate.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to get the element by the class name 'verify' and check that the preceding text matches it. So far I have

```
var verify = document.getElementsByClassName('verify');
for (var i = 0, l = verify.length; i < l; i++) {
    var x = verify[i].value;
    if (x == null || x == '') {
    }
    else {
        //This is where I need help accessing the previous text input value to compare it to the one I'm working with 
    }
}
```

This js should be able to be used on any html file, so the only thing that would be common among all of the html is that the class would be verify. So getting the elements by ID is not an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To do this with vanilla JS:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var x = 0, input; input = inputs[x]; x++) {
    if(input.type.toLowerCase() == 'password') {
        console.log(input.value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Note: This will return the first password input it finds!